# Dependencies when loading useEffect functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

How can I get loadCharityCause to be dependent on loading the loadSingleCharity useEffect()?

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadSingleCharity();
    loadCharityAthletes();
    loadCharityCause(); 
}, []);
```